# How to use the output of one query in other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I am using following query to get the output as JobId, JobName and Start Execution date

```
 SELECT
ja.job_id,
j.name AS job_name,
ja.start_execution_date,      
ja.last_executed_step_id
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
stop_execution_date is null
```

But i want to use Start_Execution_Date column in another select statement, how to do that.Please suggest

Comment: I want to use Start_execution_date and want to know the duration of particular job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @phil you can use CTE and to get the duration of your job you can use below query

```
DECLARE @minutes_running    int,
WITH myquery (job_id , job_name , start_execution_date , last_executed_step_id)
AS
(
SELECT ja.job_id, 
       j.NAME AS job_name, 
       ja.start_execution_date, 
       ja.last_executed_step_id 
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
       LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
              ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id 
       JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
         ON ja.job_id = j.job_id 
WHERE  ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id 
                        FROM   msdb.dbo.syssessions 
                        ORDER  BY agent_start_date DESC) 
       AND start_execution_date IS NOT NULL 
       AND stop_execution_date IS NULL 
       AND j.NAME = 'JOB_NAME' 
)

SELECT @minutes_running = DATEDIFF(minute,start_execution_date, getdate()) from myquery
SELECT @minutes_running as min
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a CTE (common table expression):

```
with myquery as (
SELECT
ja.job_id,
j.name AS job_name,
ja.start_execution_date,      
ja.last_executed_step_id
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
stop_execution_date is null
)
SELECT * 
FROM myquery
JOIN ....
```

[Documentation link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).